# How to create a new variable by aggregating binary items in R?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataset with 5 binary variables. Now I need to aggregate these 5 binary variables to create a new variable with which I will then run a linear regression model.

Here is part of the dataset that I have:

```
   gender race b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 score
1       M    1  0  1  1  1  1    58
2       F    1  0  1  0  0  1    63
3       M    2  1  0  1  0  0    49
4       F    5  0  1  0  0  0    54
5       F    1  0  0  1  0  1    55
.   other    4  0  0  1  0  0    71
.       M    3  1  1  0  1  1    53
.   other    4  0  1  0  1  0    68
```

I'd like to use b1, b2, b3, b4 and b5 to create a `new` variable using the `aggregate` function so that I can run a linear regression like this:

```
lm(score ~ gender + race + new, data = data)
```

My question is: how should I do to create this new variable by aggregating 5 binary variables using "sum" for the FUN argument?

Comment: How do you want to aggregate the variables? Summing? Creating a new binary variable? This is not clear at present

Comment: @CalumYou Sorry, forgot to mention it. I'd like to sum them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> transform(d1, new = rowSums(d1[paste0("b", 1:5)]))
  gender race b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 score new
1      M    1  0  1  1  1  1    58   4
2      F    1  0  1  0  0  1    63   2
3      M    2  1  0  1  0  0    49   2
4      F    5  0  1  0  0  0    54   1
5      F    1  0  0  1  0  1    55   2
6  other    4  0  0  1  0  0    71   1
7      M    3  1  1  0  1  1    53   4
8  other    4  0  1  0  1  0    68   2
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!

Answer (score 1):

Using an alternative - tidyverse - solution.
This is your data set:

```
mydf <- structure(list(gender = c("M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "other", "M","other"), 
                           race = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L), b1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
                           b2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), b3 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
                           b4 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), b5 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
                           score = c(58L, 63L, 49L, 54L, 55L, 71L, 53L, 68L)), 
                      class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Then you may create the 'new' variable using mutate and rowSums functions

```
mydf %>% 
     mutate(new = rowSums(.[starts_with("b",vars = names(.))],na.rm = TRUE))

  gender race b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 score new
1      M    1  0  1  1  1  1    58   4
2      F    1  0  1  0  0  1    63   2
3      M    2  1  0  1  0  0    49   2
4      F    5  0  1  0  0  0    54   1
5      F    1  0  0  1  0  1    55   2
6  other    4  0  0  1  0  0    71   1
7      M    3  1  1  0  1  1    53   4
8  other    4  0  1  0  1  0    68   2
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!